# Point assembly reference in .Net 4.0, cannot seem to find it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, assemblies

I'm unable to find the correct assembly reference in .Net 4.0 for the Point Structure.

The API reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.point.aspx).

But System.Windows does not exist in my Reference list from the Solution Explorer.

I understand I could have made a simple Point Structure myself but I wanted to use this in case I run into this problem with other assemblies. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Namespace:  System.Windows
>   Assembly: WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)

So you need to reference the `WindowsBase.dll` assembly. `System.Windows` is only the namespace.

Comment: Blarg, just wasn't looking hard enough. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must add WindowsBase assembly (Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)).Read MSDN carefully.

Namespace name is not always DLL name.